# How to set the IPv6 router alert option in a message

Tags: c, ipv6

I'm working with the RSVP protocol in IPv6 and in order to make it work, I have to set the IPv6 router alert in the messages that I send. I have done lots of research on internet but with no luck, maybe someone here has already done this before. You can find below the code that I use for my tests.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define DATA_LENGTH     124

int main() {
    int data_length = DATA_LENGTH;

    unsigned char data[DATA_LENGTH] = {0x10, 0x01, 0xb0, 0x16, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0x7c, 0x00, 0x18,
        0x01, 0x02, 0x20, 0x02, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x10, 0x32, 0x00, 0x20, 0xc2, 0x00, 0x18, 0x03, 0x02, 0x20, 0x02, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x20, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x18,
        0x0b, 0x02, 0x20, 0x02, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x20, 0x00, 0x00, 0x5d, 0x27, 0x00, 0x08, 0x05, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x75, 0x30, 0x00, 0x24,
        0x0c, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x07, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x7f, 0x00, 0x00, 0x05, 0x49, 0x55,
        0x9f, 0x80, 0x4a, 0xba, 0xeb, 0x90, 0x4c, 0xee, 0xa8, 0x31, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x4b, 0x00, 0x00, 
        0x05, 0xdc};

    unsigned char dest_address[16] = {0x20, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x05};

    int socket_descriptor;
    struct sockaddr_in6 dest;
    const int yes = 1;
    const int router_alert_value = 0;

    socket_descriptor = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RSVP);

    if (socket_descriptor < 0) {
        perror("Can't open socket to send path message\n");
    }

    memset(&dest, 0, sizeof(dest));

    dest.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
    memcpy(dest.sin6_addr.s6_addr, dest_address, sizeof(struct in6_addr));

    dest.sin6_port = 0;
    dest.sin6_flowinfo = 0;

    if (setsockopt(socket_descriptor, SOL_SOCKET, 
            SO_REUSEADDR,(const void *)&yes, sizeof(yes)) < 0) {
        printf("setsockopt(%d): %s\n", SO_REUSEADDR, strerror(errno));
    }

    if(setsockopt(socket_descriptor, IPPROTO_IPV6, 
            IPV6_HOPOPTS, &yes, sizeof(yes)) < 0) {
        printf("Can't set Hop-by-hop Option: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }

    if(setsockopt(socket_descriptor, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_ROUTER_ALERT, 
            (const void *) &router_alert_value, sizeof(router_alert_value)) < 0) {
        printf("Can't set IP Options: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }

    if(sendto(socket_descriptor, data, data_length, 0, 
            (struct sockaddr*) &dest, sizeof(dest)) < 0) {
        printf("Error in sending message : %s (%d)\n", strerror(errno), errno);
    }

    close(socket_descriptor);

    return(0);
}
```

The previous code compiles and sends a RSVP Path message but without the IPv6 router alert option. Since I didn't have return when I got errors with the setsockopt method, I could provide you the console output which is:

```
Can't set Hop-by-hop Option: Invalid argument
Can't set IP Options: Protocol not available
```

I have done some tries using a socket with the protocol 0 (in order to use the hop-by-hop next header) and by adding the router alert option directly into the data, but it still not working.

Any idea or leads is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure about IPv6 sockets, but otherwise when you use `SOCK_RAW` you have to create the complete packet you send, header and all. Unless `data` contains a complete IPv6 packet (with IPv6 header, RSVP header, *and* the RSVP data) then it will not work.

Comment: Yeah I thought that too, but my message is going out with a right IPv6 header and a right payload. It is just the Router Alert option which is missing. And no the 'data' just contains the RSVP header and the RSVP data only, it is just the data payload of my message.

Comment: Okay, reading [this manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ipv6.7.html) the `IPV6_ROUTER_ALERT` options doesn't *set* the router alert hop-by-hop option on the packets, instead the option causes incoming packets with the router alert hop-by-hop to be sent to the socket.

Comment: Ok, so this option is used in order to tell the socket to intercept messages which contain the router alert option (I read this page before, but was not sure about the interpretation since I didn't found another way to add this option to my message).

Comment: Yes it seems that way to me when reading it. But how to set the option on outgoing packets I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows with WinSock you can use [`IPV6_HDRINCL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738574(v=vs.85).aspx) to build the IP header and set the Router Alert flag.  On Linux and similar platforms this is simply not available and you would simply have to drop down to [raw packets](http://linux.die.net/man/7/packet) using `AF_PACKET` similar to Wireshark and `tcpdump` and hand build artisanal packets to your requirements.

Alternative of course is to propose and implement a new interface in the kernel to set IPv6 Router Alerts.